# jQuery issues with .each()

Tags: jquery

Is there any reason why this function beginning:

```
$(".inner").each(function() {
```

Would fail to process every div with the class `inner` in a page full of:

```
<div class="inner">
```

?

That is my main question.  I've pretty much debugged for the last 24 hours and I've come to the conclusion that the jQuery function is not even processing at every place it should.  This was my simple test:

```
$(function() {
    $(".inner").each(function() {
        var inner = $(this);
        var plusMore = $("<div>HELLO!!!</div>");
        plusMore.insertBefore($(inner));
    });
});
```

On identical code lines inside of a table, I only get this code to function (and view "HELLO!!!") on a handful of the table rows.  I just cannot understand it...

----**UPDATE FOR HTML/SMARTY**----

```
<td>
    {if $results[i].people}
        <div class="outer peoplecol"> 
            <div class="inner">
                {foreach from=$results[i].people item=people}
                    <div style="line-height:12px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                        {if $people.pending eq 0}
                            <a href="Editpeople.php?tid={$people.id}" title="People Details" style="text-decoration:none">
                        {/if}
                        {$people.firstName} {$people.lastName}
                        {if $people.pending eq 0}
                            </a>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                {/foreach}
            </div>
        </div>
    {else}
        <div class="outer peoplecol">
            None
        </div>
    {/if} 
</td>
```

Also - I'm using jQuery TableSorter with this.  I just tried disabling, and it worked, so it must be clashing with this...!

**---UPDATE ADDING TABLE SORTER CODE----**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    // TableSorter
    if ($("#dt-results").find("tbody").find("tr").size() > 0)
    {
        $("#dt-results") 
        .tablesorter({
                        widgets: ['zebra'], 
                        sortList: [[0,1]],
                        headers: { 
                            1: { 
                                sorter:'currency' 
                            }
                        },              
                        textExtraction: function(node) {
                            if ($(node.innerHTML).hasClass('outer') && $(node.innerHTML).hasClass('peoplecol')) {
                                if ($.trim($(node).text()) == 'None') {
                                    return 'z'; //so that none comes last
                                }
                            }
                            return $(node).text();
                        }
        })
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})
        .tablesorterFilter({filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                      filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                      filterCaseSensitive: false,
                      filterWaitTime: 10});
    }

});
```

Comment: Just a side note: since you are doing this `var inner = $(this);` you don't need to do it again here: `$(inner)`

Comment: Is all your markup correct? Closing tags etc. Have you tried `$("div.inner").each()`?

Comment: can you post sample HTML code that fails to process? Maybe post it to http://jsbin.com

Comment: I've triple checked markup on the entire page, no unclosed tags.  Indeed, I have tried `$("div.inner").each()` - same outcome.

Comment: @cheeken added my markup for this part of the table.

Comment: All - just added TableSorter code as well.  This is what is causing the headaches it seems (with this gone gone, the jQuery in question works as it should...  I don't see any conflicts however?

Comment: It is a lot less useful to us when you include code from some template language as in your HTML/SMARTY code.  We need to see the actual generated HTML - what the browser sees because we don't know how your template code gets expanded into actual HTML/JS.

Comment: I took what HTML code you had and stripped out the template stuff and made a simulated page here and add your code.  It works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dLzHb/.  There must be something else going on in the page that you're not showing us.  Are you getting an JS errors in the error console?

Comment: @jfriend00.  It looks like it is the PAGER plugin.  If I remove this line from the tablesorter:  `.tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})` The problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the way jQuery tablesorter/Pager interacted with EMPTY cells in the table.  It was causing some kind of issue with the rest of the jQuery on the page.  I never did figure out why exactly it caused problems - but as long as I forced characters (non-white space characters), all has been performing well.